# Inserting rows at end of excel table macro - Method range of object _global failed

Tags: excel, vba

Background: I have a table in excel that data will get added to over time, and to give my coworkers (who, while lovely, do not like tinkering with things in excel in fear of messing something up) an easy option for expanding the table if it fills when I'm not around, I wanted to add a macro button to add more lines to the table and fill in the formatting (some cells have IF functions in & most have conditional formatting). The idea is they can fill up to but not including the last line of the table, then hit the button and it will add 20 or so new lines before the last line of table and copy the formatting of the last line into them.
So far this is my code:

```
Sub Add_Rows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
x = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
Range(x - 1, x + 19).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
End Sub
```

I am getting a "Run time error '1004'" "Method range of object _global failed" message when I try clicking the button, and it highlights the "insert" line as being the issue. I am new to vba so any advice is welcome. If my code is utter nonsense then an alternative direction would be appreciated.
Also this is the second version, my first looped Rows.Add which worked, but was taking a few seconds so my hope was inserting 20 would be faster than adding 1 20 times!

Comment: `x - 1` and `x + 19` are not valid arguments to `Range`. I'd use something like `tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count - 1).Range.Resize(20).Insert ...` Not tested.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! That works to add the rows, however I'm not getting the formulas copied over from the last row (the formulas aren't always consistent in a column  as some columns have formulas that get overwritten by the user). Was that an error of mine before that got masked or a new one?

Comment: If you have no data below the table, you can just assign values to the rows immediately after the table. The table will automatically expand to encompass the new rows, as long as at least one cell in each row, has well defined data.

Comment: I have not tried to understand your example, except to say that you need to replace this "Range(x , y)" does not compute, if you want to refer to a cell. Try Cells(x, y). Or Range(Cells(x1, y1), Cells(x2, y2)) to select more cells. And Resize() takes two arguments, and returns a range - it does not affect anything on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub Add_Rows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim lastRow As Range, newRng As Range
    Dim newRows As Integer: newRows = 20
    
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    ' Last row
    On Error GoTo resizeOnly    ' Listrows = 0
    Set lastRow = tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count).Range
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' range of new rows
    Set newRng = tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count).Range.Resize(newRows).Offset(1)
    
    ' resize table
    tbl.Resize tbl.Range.Resize(tbl.Range.Rows.Count + newRows, tbl.Range.Columns.Count)

    ' copy last format to new rows
    lastRow.Copy
    newRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Exit Sub
    
resizeOnly:
    ' resize table
    tbl.Resize tbl.Range.Resize(tbl.Range.Rows.Count + newRows, tbl.Range.Columns.Count)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no data below the table, you can just assign values to the rows immediately after the table. The table will automatically expand to encompass the new rows, as long as at least one cell in each row, has well defined data.

```vb
' Insert 3 new rows into the listoject
' We assume the ListObject already contains data
Public Sub Test(Lob As ListObject)
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim StartRow As Long, StartCol As Long, NumCols As Long
    Dim Lst As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    ' Allocate 3 new rows
    NumCols = Lob.ListColumns.Count
    ReDim Lst(1 to 3, 1 to NumCols)
    
    
    ' Get the first column of and the first row following the list table
    StartCol = Lob.Range.Column
    StartRow = Lob.Range.row + Lob.Range.Rows.Count
    
    ' Create a range big enough to hold the data, immediately under the last row of the table.
    Set Sht = Lob.Parent
    Set Rng = Sht.Cells(StartRow, StartCol).Resize(UBound(Lst), UBound(Lst, 2))
    
    ' Add some data to the new rows
    Lst(1, 1) = "Test1"
    Lst(2, 1) = "Test2"
    Lst(3, 1) = "Test3"
    
    ' Copy data to the destination
    Rng = Lst
End Sub
```

If the list object does not contain data, ie Lob.ListRows.Count = 0, then write data after the header otherwise write it after the last rows.

There are some mistakes in your code:

- "Range(x , y)" will cause an error, when x and y are integers.  If you want to refer to a cell. Try Cells(x, y). Or Range(Cells(x1, y1), Cells(x2, y2)) to refer to more cells.
- And Resize() takes two arguments, and returns a range - it does not affect anything on the sheet.

See also how to insert rows if you want:

[Excel Range.Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Insert):

Example from the doc:

```vb
With Range("B2:E5")
    .Insert xlShiftDown
    ' Optionally clear formats, which you do not want, if you add to
    ' a table with well defined data and formats.
    .ClearFormats
End With
```

The number of the rows inserted, will equal the number of rows in the range we call Insert on.